# Close FeatherLight after opening a new one

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

I'm currently using [FeatherLight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) however I can't seem to find any documentation on hiding a previously opened box when opening a new one from inside that.

My initial link would look like:

```
<a href="{{ route('frontend.auth.login_popup') }}" class="btn ajax-featherlight" data-featherlight="ajax">{{ __('navs.frontend.login') }}</a>
```

However once this modal/popup opens, I then click another featherlight link which says "Register" so I want the login modal to close and the new one to open; but it appears the login one stays open behind the register one.

My Javascript constructor looks like the following:

```
$(".ajax-featherlight").featherlight({
    targetAttr: 'href'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can have nested featherlights is by design.

You can get close the current `featherlight` with `$.featherlight.close()`. If you don't want to close the current one but the first one opened you can call:

```
var all = $.featherlight.opened();
var first = all[0];
first.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to close the original featherlight? What if the user clicks 'cancel' on the register pop-up?